# Make automation with selenium in Python datadom bypass

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In web site shop2game.com I want to make request to add redeem code
this web site protected by datadome protection system. When I want to send request need x-datadome-client session I want to just login with `player_id` from garena and get session and after that I want to insert redeem code and my customer and buy with redeem code. Please help me how I can send request when datadome is active and I use 2captcha for bypass captcha system. Can anybody analyses this web site and show me a way to get login name session after that insert redeem code to garena server for active my user request?

I have used Python selenium for getting session data with this code:

```
async def spoof_webdriver():
    driver = None
    try:
        options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        #options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/mahdi/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default')
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        #driver.delete_all_cookies()
        driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined});")
        driver.get('https://shop2game.com/?language=en&app=100067')
        #wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        print("website is opnening .... ")
        time.sleep(20)
        print("website is opne")
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
        cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    
        return cookies
    finally:
        if driver:
            try:
                driver.quit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error closing browser: {e}")
            print("Browser closed")
# اجرای حلقه asyncio

cookies = asyncio.run(spoof_webdriver())

# URL ارسال فرم لاگین
login_url = 'https://shop2game.com/api/auth/player_id_login'

# داده‌های فرم لاگین
data = {"app_id":100067,"login_id":"34234324234","app_server_id":0}
# ارسال یک درخواست اولیه

# ارسال درخواست POST به سرور برای لاگین
cookies_dict = {cookie['name']: cookie['value'] for cookie in cookies}
print(cookies_dict)

session_key = cookies_dict.get('session_key')
print("sessiont key :" + str(session_key))
datadom = cookies_dict['datadome']
response = requests.post(login_url, json=data,cookies=cookies_dict)
response.close()
print(str(response))

pay_url = 'https://shop2game.com/api/shop/pay/init?language=en®ion=ME'
data = {
    "service": "pc",
    "app_id": 100067,
    "packed_role_id": 0,
    "channel_id": 299999,
    "channel_data": {
        "card_password": "123123123123",
        "card_no": "123123123123",
        "friend_username": None
    },
    "experiment": {},
    "revamp_experiment": {
        "session_id": session_key,  # اینجا session_key را استفاده می‌کنیم.
        "group": "control2"
    }
}
response = requests.post(login_url, json=data,cookies=cookies_dict)
print ("response2 = "+ str(response))
```

but response is datadome code error.

Comment: THis might be illegal.